# ¿Como crear un archivo con los datos de un InputStream mediante comandos?

Tags: java, android

He formulado esta pregunta para poder resolver mi duda o obstáculo que es:

Quiero lograr poder crear un archivo pero no vació ya creado con sus  datos desde el terminal de comandos.

**Por que desde la terminal de comandos y no desde java con la clase File y OutputStream?**
Porque necesito poder crearlo desde la terminal de comandos,porque mi aplicación usa permisos Root y lo que estoy realizando son movimientos Root desde mi aplicación desde comandos, porque no se como hacerlo o conozco una forma de hacerlo desde código java.

**Mi comando actual solo crea un archivo vació.**

```
String[] command2 = {"su", "-c", "touch", Ruta del archivo};
    try{
    Process proc2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command2);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Si", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

**Pequeña información:**
en mi investigación encontré algo referente al comando vi, pero saque la conclusión de solo es un editor de texto de archivos txt, pero no se si tenga mas funciones.

**Si conocen alguna forma de lograr mi objetivo por favor comunicármela. Gracias**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: App con permiso root**

> **ADVERTENCIA 1:** Modificar archivos de sistema podría dañar el equipo, si no se sabe lo que se está haciendo.
>
> **ADVERTENCIA 2:** Esto existe en SO en inglés: [este es el enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7102780/5587982).

**Fuente de este código:** [ver aquí](http://muzikant-android.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html)

```
public abstract class ExecuteAsRootBase
{
   public static boolean canRunRootCommands()
   {
      boolean retval = false;
      Process suProcess;

      try
      {
         suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

         DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
         DataInputStream osRes = new DataInputStream(suProcess.getInputStream());

         if (null != os && null != osRes)
         {
            // Getting the id of the current user to check if this is root
            os.writeBytes("id\n");
            os.flush();

            String currUid = osRes.readLine();
            boolean exitSu = false;
            if (null == currUid)
            {
               retval = false;
               exitSu = false;
               Log.d("ROOT", "Can't get root access or denied by user");
            }
            else if (true == currUid.contains("uid=0"))
            {
               retval = true;
               exitSu = true;
               Log.d("ROOT", "Root access granted");
            }
            else
            {
               retval = false;
               exitSu = true;
               Log.d("ROOT", "Root access rejected: " + currUid);
            }

            if (exitSu)
            {
               os.writeBytes("exit\n");
               os.flush();
            }
         }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         // Can't get root !
         // Probably broken pipe exception on trying to write to output stream (os) after su failed, meaning that the device is not rooted

         retval = false;
         Log.d("ROOT", "Root access rejected [" + e.getClass().getName() + "] : " + e.getMessage());
      }

      return retval;
   }

   public final boolean execute()
   {
      boolean retval = false;

      try
      {
         ArrayList<String> commands = getCommandsToExecute();
         if (null != commands && commands.size() > 0)
         {
            Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());

            // Execute commands that require root access
            for (String currCommand : commands)
            {
               os.writeBytes(currCommand + "\n");
               os.flush();
            }

            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();

            try
            {
               int suProcessRetval = suProcess.waitFor();
               if (255 != suProcessRetval)
               {
                  // Root access granted
                  retval = true;
               }
               else
               {
                  // Root access denied
                  retval = false;
               }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               Log.e("ROOT", "Error executing root action", ex);
            }
         }
      }
      catch (IOException ex)
      {
         Log.w("ROOT", "Can't get root access", ex);
      }
      catch (SecurityException ex)
      {
         Log.w("ROOT", "Can't get root access", ex);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         Log.w("ROOT", "Error executing internal operation", ex);
      }

      return retval;
   }
   protected abstract ArrayList<String> getCommandsToExecute();
}
```

---

**Edit: Código para Android, no me había percatado**
Puedes hacerlo perfectamente en android. Está explicado de una forma clara y en español en [developer android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Código para Aplicaciones de escritorio**
En Java puedes perfectamente crear un archivo vacío y agregarle contenido, crear un archivo a partir de otro, o escribir contenido en un archivo que ya exista, borrarlo, etc. Eso sí, no intentes hacer nada en un archivo que exista en un directorio del cual no tengas permiso de acceso, porque como es natural no será posible.

Ejemplo de crear un archivo que no exista y agregarle contenido. Este ejemplo buscará un archivo llamado logfile.txt y si no lo encuentra lo crea, en el directorio especificado en la variable p del tipo Path:
Tomado de la [doc de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LogFileTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Convert the string to a
    // byte array.
    String s = "Hello World! ";
    byte data[] = s.getBytes();
    Path p = Paths.get("./logfile.txt");

    try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(
      Files.newOutputStream(p, CREATE, APPEND))) {
      out.write(data, 0, data.length);
    } catch (IOException x) {
      System.err.println(x);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Un problema es que para hacer movimientos root solo puedo utilizar comandos (creo) porque si lo hago desde java directamente falla y la clase Files no se encuentra para android. Gracias

Comment: Se puede hacer lo que deseas sin problema. Mira la respuesta editada y el enlace a la doc de android, además está en español.

Comment: Muy útil su apoyo, pero el gran problema es que necesito crear este archivo en un directorio protegido que no accede con las clases de java solo mediante comandos root. Gracias

Comment: No entiendo lo de un _directorio protegido_. De acuerdo a Android puedes acceder por programación java a donde quieras, con tal de tener los permisos para ello, otorgados en el manifest. De Android: _Todos los dispositivos Android tienen dos áreas de almacenamiento de archivos: el almacenamiento "interno" y "externo". Estos nombres vienen de los primeros tiempos de Android, cuando la mayoría de los dispositivos ofrecían una memoria no volátil integrada (almacenamiento interno), más un medio de almacenamiento extraíble como una tarjeta micro SD (almacenamiento externo). Algunos dispositivos..._

Comment: El directorio root del que hablas ¿dónde se encuentra en el dispositivo android o dónde?

Comment: Si pero el problema es que el archivo que quiero crear es la carpeta /system un directorio que solo se permite escritura o lectura y el permiso root te permite desafiar esas condiciones, por eso necesito realizarlo desde comandos,porque de otra manera no se podrá porque mi programa no tiene la capacidad, porque ya que en linux hay muchas cosas relacionadas al super usuario y eso, que te limitan las capacidades . No puedo realizarlo desde java ya me debo meter a los comandos para desafiar esas leyes (Esto es lo que entiendo). Gracias

Comment: Haberlo dicho más claro. He editado la pregunta. En SO en inglés hay un hilo con una solución usando el código que he puesto. Hay comentarios en el referido hilo y explicaciones en el otro enlace.

Comment: Ok su contenido es maravilloso y esplendido para el ejecutamientos de comandos root pero todavía no se como crear el archivo con el contenido o con alguna manera de escribir contenido en el. Muchas gracias.

Comment: La clase tiene un método llamado `public final boolean execute()` que indica cómo pasar un ArrayList con comandos root. Te tocaria modificarla para pasarle los comandos (en este caso de creación o edición de los archivos que quieras), tal como harías desde la línea de comandos.  Eso sí, como dice la advertencia, si pasas un comando mal puedes dañar el dispositivo.

Comment: Pero continua mi duda ya yo se pasar y crear archivos mi duda es como puedo añadirle contenido desde un comando. Gracias